# How to determine what public DNS is being used?

Tags: domain-name-system

How do I determine the public DNS resolver that's being used to resolve public internet addresses from laptop connected to a network? I can only see the internal DNS resolver address from running ipconfig in Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `dig whoami.akamai.net`. The Akamai DNS servers are set to respond to this name with the IP address of the server that requested it, so that shows you the farthest upstream dns server in that chain.

Otherwise, no. Unless somebody decides to advertise it, there's no way to find out who their upstream DNS is.

Comment: This is the right answer. I would add that you might want to repeat the test a few times in case your provider is load balancing the outbound queries. You can also setup your own "DNS reflector" service. I coded one as part of my Golang learning: https://github.com/pjperez/whoami

Comment: Thanks looks like dig also just shows the local DNS resolver assigned from the DHCP server.

Comment: Yes, it does tell you the local DNS resolver. But the A record that whoami returns is the requesting server's address.

Comment: More details/background/context here: https://superuser.com/a/606249/98033.  Also: thanks @PedroPerez for sharing https://github.com/pjperez/whoami with us.

Answer (score 1):

I used dnscrypt had the same problem but found a useful site ipleak.net that does exactly that, and then also shows all the dns servers that your isp had.

Using dig whoami.akamai.net also works, but it only shows ip but not the details.